# Copying cURL Cookies To The Accessing User (With Javascript?)

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, curl

What I want to do is show an iframe of a "logged in" website. For example, let's say I wanted to show you your Gmail account (logged in) in an iframe.

So what I did is used cURL to login. The login script works perfectly. I have the cookiejar set to cookie.txt as below...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt **($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");**
```

The login itself is working perfectly! The problem is that when I try to iframe it, it says you need to login because the Cookies are being held by the server (on cookie.txt) and iframes are rendered on client side.

So, what I need to do, is take the cookies in that cookie.txt and write them to a similar file on the users computer. I am thinking you use Javascript to do this?

Comment: Javascript is unnecessary, you're already using PHP which supports cookies just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write anything to a file on the users pc with javascript.

Even if you had the cookies on the client side (maybe getting it from your server via ajax) you would not be able to set a cookie to another domain.

I think your only option here is to proxy the website to the user, meaning the iframe would actually point to a php script on your server that would request the external page sending in the cookies and then show it to the user.

Edit

Also, if the user types in his login and password on your page, or if you have it stored in your server, you can put it into a form with the target set to the iframe and submit it to the login page.

Comment: Yes, but that isnt any different than just echoing the HTML from the cURL, which doesn't work because the CSS is messed up...

but thanks for answering!

Comment: I don't know but maybe your CSS problem might be solved by adding a base tag to the HTML resulting from the cURL.